# Issue with creating base generic view class

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance, view

I try to create base class for all custom views which will also include presenter and binding. But I can't implement generics inheritance. Please point me where I am wrong

```
public abstract class BasePresenterView<T extends View> extends BaseView<T>{
public BasePresenterView(Context context){
    this(context, null);
}

public BasePresenterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}


private void init(Context context) {
    injectViews(createView(context));
}

private View createView(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = null;
    if (inflater != null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(getLayout(), null);
    }
    return view;
}

private void injectViews(View view) {
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
}

public abstract Subscription bind();

protected abstract int getLayout();}
```

and BaseView class

```
public abstract class BaseView<T extends View>{}
```

The problem is that I can't call super method. 
Here is how I want to use it:

```
public class ToolBarLiker extends BasePresenterView<Toolbar>{

public ToolBarLiker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public Subscription bind(){
    return Subscriptions.from();
}

@Override
protected int getLayout(){
    return R.layout.toolbar_liker_tab;
}
}
```

So implementation of inflating and finding views are hiden
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with I can't call super method? - What exact methods do you mean and can you give a code example what is not working.

Comment: hi Kevin, I can't cal super  constructor of passed generic android View class

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public abstract class BaseView<T extends View>{}
```

with

```
public abstract class BaseView<T extends View> extends View {
    public BaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.
Good luck.